# Specifying a method-signature with an object parameter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I'm implementing a composite component in which I need to work with a command button that will delete a row from a datatable. The objets might have not been persisted in the database (depends on an action confirmation) so I can not work with ids.

I know that I can specify string or Integer but it is possible to specify an object in the in the interface as a parameter for the action in this radio button, how it should be done (specifying the class path or not)? The object is a DTO that I manage in a backed bean:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="objectList" />
    <cc:attribute name="removeButtonAction" 
            method-signature="void removeObjectDto(ObjectDto)" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:datatable id="myDatatable" var="objectRow" value="{#cc.attrs.objectList}">
        ...
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Delete Action</f:facet>
            <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{cc.attrs.removeButtonAction(objectRow)}" >
                <f:ajax execute=":myDatatable" render=":myDatatable" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:datatable>
</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: I've find out the answer, the default class is a java.lang.object so it wouldm't be possible, i've generated an identifier just for rendering the objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need pass your full path like this:

```
<cc:attribute name="yourMethodName" method-signature="void yourMethodName(br.com.yourPath.YourClassName)" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that only java.lang.objects were allowed